# Discovered answer to my own question but haven't tested it - should I answer?

Tags: discussion

I asked a [question about AWS ECS images](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/1227/copy-aws-ecs-repositorys-contents-to-s3-bucket). No one's answered so I reached out to AWS' support and got the barebones steps to solve my problem.

I haven't tested it yet but it seems sound in theory. Should I;

1. Post the answer I got from amazon as a "I haven't tried it but this is what they told me" as it's a general answer that could help others.
2. Wait until I test it and post my exact steps on the grounds that it'll be more precise? (which could be a couple weeks)

Answer (score 5):

Why not do both?

I get that the solutions from AWS Support are pretty good, but you also need to do a bit of work to actually test them out.

So,

> Post the answer I got from amazon as "I haven't tried it but this is what they told me" as it's a general answer that could help others.

Do this making the disclaimer clear, and then, once you have actually tested it, then add a note confirming it.

Answer (score 3):

In my humble opinion,  answers are more useful once battlefield confirmed. There's no urge to self answer yourself.

Anyway that's a nice move from you to think about following your question and giving the solution you have found for future readers stuck on the same problem.  Personally I'd test and confirm and then answer giving the credits for the first step to AWS support and add whatever tweak you had to do or a sentence saying it was the straight  to the point solution once tested.

Whatever you choose,  self answer are very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can post the answer, then after testing you can update and accept your answer as correct.